# Having trouble getting mysql_real_escape_string() to work properly

Tags: php, sql, security, sql-injection

For preventing sql injections I tried this:

```
$db = new myConnectDB();
                        
$beerName = mysql_real_escape_string($beerName);
$beerID = mysql_real_escape_string($beerID);
$brewery = mysql_real_escape_string($brewery);
$style = mysql_real_escape_string($style);
$userID = mysql_real_escape_string($userID);
$abv = mysql_real_escape_string($abv);
$ibu = mysql_real_escape_string($ibu);
$breweryID = mysql_real_escape_string($breweryID);
$icon = mysql_real_escape_string($icon);
                        
                        
$beerName = addslashes($beerName);
$brewery = addslashes($brewery);
$brewery = str_replace('\'', '', $brewery);
$query3 = "INSERT INTO uniqueBeers (userID,beerID,beerName,beerStyle,beerBrewery,abv,ibu,breweryID,icon, brewIcon) VALUES ($userID, '$beerID', '$beerName', '$style' , '$brewery', '$abv','$ibu','$breweryID', '$icon', '$iconBrew')";
$db->query($query3);
```

But I get all sorts of error like:

> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user
>
> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user

After reading the errors and doing some reasearch online I noticed i could pass a connection in and I tried this:

```
$beerName = mysql_real_escape_string($beerName,$db);
```

for all the above entries but it also did not work so Now I am a little stuck.

Update:

Here is the contents of myConnectDB with my database info taken out

```
<?php

class myConnectDB extends mysqli{
    
    public function __construct($hostname='localhost',  
        $user='',
        $password='', 
        $dbname=''){
        parent::__construct($hostname, $user, $password, $dbname);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: your user is denied from inserting data, its not mysql-real-escape I guess

Comment: What is `$db`?  i.e. What does `myConnectDB` do?

Comment: Are you using the MySQL extension to connect to your DB?

Comment: Are you sure that the connection was successfull?

Comment: As a side-note your should consider some kind of parameterized statements.

Comment: I updated the post with what my connectDB does. Also I am sure it connects because when I take out the mysql_real_escape_string calls it submits to my database perfectly.

Comment: Aren't `mysql_real_escape_string` and `mysqli` part of different mysql bindings?

Comment: Also may I ask why all the downvotes? I have updated my post to give the most information possible, and I do not understand why all the down votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the mysqli extension to connect with your DB (assuming this is successful), but you are using a MySQL function later in your script. The equivalent mysqli (procedural) function is [mysqli_real_escape_string($dbLink,$stringToEscape)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) - Note the extra `i` (for Improved). However, you have a mysqli object, so you should use the object oriented style:

```
$beerName = $db->real_escape_string($beerName);  // OOP
```

Also, once you have corrected the above, then you do not require the following lines of code:

```
$beerName = addslashes($beerName);
$brewery = addslashes($brewery);
$brewery = str_replace('\'', '', $brewery);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if "you should be using" is the right way to say this. It certainly fixes his problem, but he probably should be using some kind of parameterized statement.

Comment: Just tried that and now I am down to one error:

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

I am not sure what variable from my code above to pass as the second. I tried $db, and that didn't work. WHen I try with the $db as the second argument I get this error:

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli

Comment: @w3d after trying your above change I got this error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function string()

Comment: Sorry, those should be underscores (`_`), not hyphens (`-`) (where did they come from!? ;) The method call should be `real_escape_string()`

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you very very much. Also thank you for not down voting my question. I dont get when users downvote and don't even tell you why.

Comment: One more quick question, about how much protection will this give?

Comment: This should protect you against [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). However, as suggested earlier, for new code you should probably be looking at parameterised statements (query binding). You then don't need to explicitly escape everything. Have a look at [prepare()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and [bind_param()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the sequence of your functions.
You need to have a valid access to your database first.
The message tells you that you don't have, and the code shows that you instiated `$db = new myConnectDB();` but you have never connected to the database.